# Freemember: Redirect user to previous page after login

Tags: login, redirects, freemember

Is it possible to redirect the user to the previous page after login, without needing to use PHP?

Note: I'm not using the default login, i'm using the Freemember add-on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As you're using [FreeMember](https://exp-resso.com/freemember) you can take advantage of its built-in `PREVIOUS_URL` constant:

```
{exp:freemember:login return="PREVIOUS_URL"}
```

As detailed in the [FreeMember login form docs on GitHub](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/wiki/Login-Tag).

If you were using the built in `login_form` tag instead, I'd suggest you <strike>use something like the [Current URL](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/current-url-ee2) extension (EE2 version linked)</strike> use the incredibly useful [Mo'Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables), to achieve the same effect:

```
{exp:member:login_form return="{current_url}"}
```

This works as you can [pass a full URL as the return parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#return) to the `login_form` tag. That way you're good for any URL structure you might have in your site.

Comment: Hey Tom, i'm actually using the Freemember add-on but it uses the some of the same tags as the standard login_form tag.

Comment: Might be worth updating + tagging your qn with that info.

Comment: Oh my gosh. "Grabs more coffee and hangs head in shame". Completely missed that constant on the Github page. Thanks Tom.

Comment: No worries, easily done :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
{exp:member:login_form return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}"}
```

Maybe you will need to add segment if you have more than 3.

Comment: Note that this is different to `PREVIOUS_URL`, which refers to the page they visited **before** the login page (your answer would just return them to the current page, so would be more useful in a header login form etc).

Comment: @AdrianMacneil Indeed, I don't deserve my 2 votes ;)

Comment: Well, depends on the question. I think you had a good answer for the original question before it was edited :)

Answer (score 3):

There's also this excellent add-on by Objective HTML that adds redirect on login and logout: [Authenticate](https://objectivehtml.com/authenticate)

Comment: I need to borrow the constant from Free Member. return="PREVIOUS_URL" is a good idea.

Comment: If you want to keep it consistent, bear in mind that our `PREVIOUS_URL` constant refers to the page they last visited **before** the login page, not the current page. See the code if I didn't explain that clearly.